# Загрузить страничку из интернета для парсинга

Tags: python, lxml

ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как загрузить страничку из интернета и запарсить её. вот код с тремя примерами. не работает третий пример

```
import lxml.html
import requests

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring("""<html>
 <body>
   <span class="simple_text">One</span> tehfghhxt</br>
   <span class="cyrillic_text">Второй</span> cyrcyrcyr</br>
 </body>
</html>
""")
txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="simple_text"]/text()[1]')
print(txt1)

print('-----------')

string = open('html.html', 'r').read()
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="simple_text"]/text()[1]')
print(txt1)

print('-----------')

url = 'http://google.ru/'
req = requests.get(url)
string = req.text
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)
txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/span[@class="simple_text"]/text()[1]')
print(txt1)
```

помогите пожалуйста исправить

Comment: Никакого класса simple_text там нет, например.

Comment: (1) "не работает третий пример" -- не очень специфично: что печатает? что должен напечатать? (с разных ip можно разные результаты получить, даже если рассчитывать (не нужно) что люди запустять этот пример) (2) первые два примера не имеют отношения к загрузке из интернета.

Answer (score 1):

для третьего способа

```
from lxml.html import parse

root = parse(url)
txt1 = root.xpath('//a/b.....')
```

Когда lxml.html.parse не может распарсить страничку (например происходит редирект и пр.), объект для парсинга необходимо получить стандартными библиотеками:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import parse

root = parse(urlopen(url))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib` и  `urllib2` вам в помощь. В парсинге может `Beautiful Soup` помочь.